# Message mapping not done in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I am working on spring web socket. i just create a controller for calling apis through WS. but unfortunately its mapping is not done. so i cant call that apis from client.

This is my controller class

```
@Controller
public class FloorController {
@MessageMapping("/floormapupdate")
    public Message greeting(@Header(value = "nativeHeaders") Map s, Principal principal, Message message) throws Exception {
        String type = (String) ((List) (s.get("type"))).get(0);
        Map headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("type", type);

        System.out.println("===================" + principal.getName());
        simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/channel/me", message);
        return message;
    }
}
```

what is the issue with it ?